# Spring Boot : Error - "Method execute from jdbcTemplate referes to missing DataAccessException"

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and trying out few examples demonstrated on Spring's site.
I get above error while trying this simple example - https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/ .

I am facing a compiler error saying - 'The method execute(String) from the type JdbcTemplate refers to the missing type DataAccessException'.

Image -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PL0m.jpg

I did search other resources to get rid of this issue where spring-tx/ spring.transations such jars were suggested to attach. Nothing has worked in my case.

POM.xml has following dependancy -

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added for COnsuming Restful services guide -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Following three Added for Validating form validate with spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Following two are Added for relational data access using spring guide -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Please help me out if anyone can ? Thanks a ton!

Updating the maven dependency tree for **spring-boot-starter-jdbc**:

```
com.kurshit.springrest:SpringRest:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicat
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplica
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
|  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.6.6; omitted for
|  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for
|  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.7.22; omitted for
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  |  +- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  |     \- (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile - omitted for duplicate
|  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for dupli
|  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
|  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
|  |  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicat
|  |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test - omitted for
|  +- (com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplica
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
|  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
|  |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplica
|  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
|  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplica
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - scope updated from test; omit
|  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
|     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
+- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
|  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
|  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
|  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
|  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.7.16; scope updated from t
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for dupli
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for d
|  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
|  |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile (version managed from 3.16.1-GA)
|  |  |  +- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - version managed from 1.6.6; omitted for dup
|  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
|     +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.13:compile (version managed from 2.4.3)
|     \- (org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.1.4.RELEASE;
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile (version managed from 3.3.0.Final)
|  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile (version managed from 1.3.1)
+- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
|  +- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for dupli
|  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
|        +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|        \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
\- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:compile
```

Comment: Can you do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and post the result?

Comment: Since the required dependency is there I suspect this is an eclipse problem.
1. compile your code using maven to verify the issue exists only in eclipse.
2. update the maven dependencies in eclipse (Sorry, don't remember how to do that)
3. compare the dependencies visible in Eclipse with those from Maven.

Comment: I had dependency conflicts for two versions for sring-tx at my maven repo. Deleting the other did the trick and resolved the issue. Thank you all for valuable insights to this.

Comment: could you make that an answer and eventually accept it, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency (you might have to adjust the version to be compatible with your Spring Boot version)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Edited:
  Deleting the conflicting dependancies from maven repo got me rid of this compilation error.

Comment: OP uses Spring Boot 1.59 so he probably should use the 4.x version. AND it should get pulled in any way, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure if the JDBC starter brings in the transactional deps - let's see what the tree output gives.

Comment: spring-jdbc does: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.13.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.pom

Comment: Creating a project with the above pom and then attempting to call execute on JDBCTemplate does not result in a compile error, as as you say, it pulls in the spring-tx jar.

Obviously something else going on, maybe the MAVEN resolve has failed or something like that.

Comment: spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE has dependency for spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE (as updated in above dependancy tree). Why do I need to add this dependency externally ? Shouldn't it have pulled it in itself ?

Comment: I had dependency conflicts for two versions for sring-tx at my maven repo. Deleting the other did the trick and resolved the issue. Thank you all for valuable insights to this.